# Classifications of nilpotent orbits in Lie algebras

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, invariant-theory

Nilpotent orbits in $\mathfrak{sl}_{n}$ are in one to one correspondence with the set of partitions.

Nilpotent orbits in $\mathfrak{so}_{2n+1}$ are in one to one correspondence with the set of partitions of 2n+1 in which even parts occur with even multiplicity.

Nilpotent orbits in $\mathfrak{sp}_{2n}$ are in one to one correspondence with the set of partitions of 2n in which odd parts occur with even multiplicity.

I wonder if these statements can be generalized to the most general case.

Comment: What generality do you want?

Comment: Can these statements be generalized to linear Lie algebras or any Lie algebras?

Comment: There might be some informations in "Nilpotent orbits in semisimple Lie algebras : An introduction" by Collingswood and McGovern.

Answer (score 0):

There is no analogous statement for the exceptional Lie algebras, if this is the generalization you want. The nilpotent orbits in that case are classified using the Bala-Carter theory.